# libpng warnings about sRGB profiles - determine which files are meant and disable warning

Tags: color, png, color-profile

After some LaTeX or system updates, I get these new warnings for something that was typeset perfectly before:

> libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited

Since it's a large document with many chapters, I get like dozens of these. The PNGs almost certainly come all out of Gimp or Photoshop.

- is it possible to show *which* images are affected?
- is it possible to turn off these annoying warnings?

I am using PDFLaTeX on Linux. The images have been created under OS X.

Comment: @darthbith - please note that the linked question does not address the two specific questions I have (bullet points)

Comment: Noted. Some research shows that the problem is in `libpng`, not in the TeX system, and that turning off the warnings probably requires specifying options to `libpng`. Nonetheless, you can eliminate the warnings by the method suggested in the linked question :-)

Comment: @Werner I wish this question was not closed as a duplicate. I would like an answer that addresses the question as to how these warnings can be disabled.  The other question referenced as already having an answer only answers how to show and fix images, but not actually to disable the warnings.